# Inserting date into a texarea in the current position is not getting applied

Tags: reactjs

I am using React 16.8+. I have a use case where I have to enter the selected date from a calendar control in the current cursor location of the textbox when a button is clicked. I can for sure get the current date values from the calendar control, but when I am trying to insert that value in the current cursor location, all hell breaks loose.

Here is my code.

The Button Click

```
<Button
  style={{ float: "right" }}
  onClick={insertDate}
  type="primary"
  size="small"
  shape="round"
>
  Select Date
</Button>;
```

TextArea element

```
<textarea
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  rows="4"
  id="actions_area"
  ref={textAreaEl}
  onChange={onChange}
>
  {content}
</textarea>;
```

Refs

```
const textAreaEl = useRef(null);
```

and finally the button click -

```
const insertDate = (e) => {
  let textToInsert = chosenDate;
  let cursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.selectionStart;
  let textBeforeCursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.value.substring(
    0,
    cursorPosition
  );
  let textAfterCursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.value.substring(
    cursorPosition,
    textAreaEl.current.value.length
  );
  let updatedText =
    textBeforeCursorPosition + textToInsert + textAfterCursorPosition;
  // target.value = updatedText
  textAreaEl.current.value = updatedText;
};
```

When the button click is happening, nothing is being inserted in the current location of the textarea. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thank you for your time and patience.

**Update**

As per the answer mentioned below , I did update the code to be as follows

```
    let textToInsert = chosenDate;
    let cursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.selectionStart;
    let textBeforeCursorPosition = text.substring(0, cursorPosition);
    let textAfterCursorPosition = text.substring(cursorPosition, text.length);
    let updatedText =
      textBeforeCursorPosition + textToInsert + textAfterCursorPosition;
    console.log(updatedText)
    setText(updatedText)
```

So now I can confirm that the `setText` is working fine and the content is working fine but the date is not inserted in the correct place ..

```
test → date will be inserted here ← after date content1606535285808test → date will be inserted here ← after date content
```

The above is the output I am receiving. I had placed the cursor between the two → ← but the entire text gets appended to the existing text.

Comment: Don't change the value of DOM textarea, instead change the last row 
` textAreaEl.current.value = updatedText;` 
to something like: ` setContent(updatedText);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` should be a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and your `insertDate` function should update the state binded to the `textarea`

```
<textarea
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  rows="4"
  id="actions_area"
  ref={textAreaEl}
  onChange={onChange}
  value={content}
/>;
```

```
const insertDate = (e) => {
  let textToInsert = chosenDate;
  let cursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.selectionStart;
  let textBeforeCursorPosition = content.substring(0, cursorPosition);
  let textAfterCursorPosition = content.substring(cursorPosition, content.length);
  let updatedText =
    textBeforeCursorPosition + textToInsert + textAfterCursorPosition;
  setContent(updatedText);
};
```

I'm guessing your `onChange` handler is already updating that state too.

Comment: I updated my question based on your suggestion . thanks

Comment: @Gagan is `text` a different state? you should update the same state you're assigning to `textarea`

Comment: Managed to resolve it. Please see my answer below. However since you answer guided me in the right direction, I am going to mark your answer as the correct answer - Thanks for all the help kind Sir/Ma'am.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me.

```
  const insertDate = (e) => {
    let textToInsert = chosenDate;
    let cursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.textarea.selectionStart;
    let textBeforeCursorPosition = text.substring(0, cursorPosition);
    let textAfterCursorPosition = text.substring(cursorPosition, text.length);
    let updatedText =
      textBeforeCursorPosition + textToInsert + textAfterCursorPosition;
    setText(updatedText);
  }
```

This is almost the same as @diedu's answer above, except that I am doing this

```
let cursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.textarea.selectionStart;
```

instead of this

```
let cursorPosition = textAreaEl.current.selectionStart;
```

Thanks